# What is a copy of a valid state ID for a bus system application

Tags: usa, paperwork, buses, michigan

I'm about to get a bus pass for reduced fare in the state of Michigan, I qualify with both Scoliosis and Autism. But, reading the application, it states a copy of a valid ID must be enclosed. This means a valid ID card, right? Or does a printed copy of both side suffice? Just checking to make sure. southeast Michigan SMARTbus system.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, and it might be easier for for a Travel.SE reader to respond if we could see the application page itself. In any event, the SMARTbus system surely doesn't want to keep track of its applicants' original documents: receive, have custody, return when done, and respond to "where's my document" questions. If I were you, I'd submit copies with my application. If they want originals, they'll let you know.

Answer (score 2):

The [form](https://www.smartbus.org/Portals/0/Documents/Website%20Docs/Application%20docs/2019.5%20Disabled%20ID%20Application.pdf) appears to state explicitly that a printed color copy of both sides will suffice:

> A color copy of applicant’s
> State of Michigan driver
> license or ID is acceptable.